# Work with a SSH connect rate limitation in the firewall

Tags: ssh, firewall

My university uses a firewall which limits the SSH connect rate. Since I often do one-off `scp` or `rsync` commands, I quickly run into that rate limitation.

Is there some way to use a persistent SSH connection for moving single files to the remote computer?

Comment: Do they allow regular interactive logins and is your client OpenSSH?  If so, you should be able to use the multiplexing in OpenSSH to do it (look at ControlMaster in the ssh_config man page).

Comment: I am trying this, and it still takes a long time to log in. And after a couple times logging in and out, it still freezes. Is there some way to check whether it used the ControlMaster?

Comment: So the idea with the ControlMaster is that you'd do one interactive login that you'd leave logged in.  Then subsequent logins would reuse that same connection instead of opening a new one.  One easy way to check if it's doing the right thing is to log into the server twice and look at how many sshd's you have running.  Without ControlMaster you'll have 2, with it you'll have 1.